# Converting few indexes of the list to hex

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have an integer list arr with five elements/indexes ranging from arr[0] to arr[4]

The last three elements are customer number which ranges from 01 to 250,000. What I need is to convert them to hex in such a way that the array should look like:

For customer 1,
`arr = [00,00,01,00,00]` - cust num is the last three bytes

For customer 2,
`arr = [00,00,02,00,00]` - cust num is the last three bytes

For customer 250,000,
`arr = [00,00,90,d0,03]` - cust num is the last three bytes, ***250,000 in hex = 3D090***

I know I can use hex() function to individually convert the indexes to hex or can convert the whole array to hex, but how do I convert the value to hex and place it in last three bytes as in the above format?

Comment: So you have a nested list?

Comment: This is just a sample of what I'm trying to achieve. If I get to know how do I convert the last three bytes to hex in the above format, I can modify the code accordingly :) Yes, the original program has a nested list..

Comment: I think what's going on here is a misunderstanding of what "hex" is. It is but a way of representing a number, therefore you don't really need to store it in hex, you can just convert it on the go, and as to how to split it into numbers representing 2 digits... 1 hex digit can represent 16 numbers (0-15), therefore 2 represent 16x16=256 (0-255) so you get last 2 by 250 000 % 256 = 144 (90 in hex), next 2 you get by (250 000/256)%256 and so on. Just be careful with division, you always want it rounded down here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
i = 250000

constant = ['00', '00']

result = [constant + [first + second 
                      for first, second in zip(string[::2], string[1::2])][::-1] 
          for string in (f'{i:X}'.zfill(6) for i in range(1, 250001))]
print(result[0])
print(result[-1])
```

For Python <= 3.5:

```
i = 250000

constant = ['00', '00']

result = [constant + [first + second 
                      for first, second in zip(string[::2], string[1::2])][::-1] 
          for string in ('{:X}'.format(i).zfill(6) for i in range(1, 250001))]
print(result[0])
print(result[-1])
```

Output:

```
['00', '00', '01', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '90', 'D0', '03']
```

Explanation:

First, we recognise that we can use string formatting to convert each number into a string, which is then padded to length 6 with `0` if needed.

Next, we chunk the string into two-character blocks and reverse it so that it has the representation required.

Lastly, we add two `'00'` strings to each inner `list`.

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for, but when I try to compile this, I get the following error: for string in (f'{i:X}'.zfill(6) for i in range(1, 250001))]
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @AmithPV You're probably using Python <= 3.5. I'll include a modification for earlier Python versions.

Comment: Thanks! I am using Python 2.7.9 and your modified code worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Might help

```
import re
def split_hex_rev(number):
    arr = re.findall('..',hex(number).replace('x',''))
    while len(arr)<5:
        arr.append('00')
    arr.reverse()
    return arr
```